# How do I setup the Heroku CLI app?

Tags: heroku

It's a pretty simple problem. I need to get my `heroku` CLI app working with an app I have. I already have the git repo checked out (from github though, not sure if that matters).

A google search suggests this page is the place to go to get help, but the page doesn't tell me anything useful:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already checked out the code all you need to need is setup a git remote pointing at heroku.

1. Locate your apps Gtit url - easiest place is from the 'My Apps' on Heroku in the 'Git Repo' panel, it will look something like `git@heroku.com:stark-beach-5145.git`
2. Back in your local git repo do (replacing with your app URL):

   git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:stark-beach-5145.git

Now you will be able to perform `git push heroku` etc.

However, if you just want to use `heroku` commands as long as you explicitly pass in the application name you don't actually need to perform steps 1 and 2 above. eg

```
heroku ps --app <appname>
```

would show you the running processes for your application etc. Here appname is the name of the app as listed on the 'My Apps' page.